# Python (Pandas): How do I upload the text file below by the name (last column)

Tags: pandas

```
This is a header to be ignored
20001001   23.0   5   X   1   Kevin
20001002   23.1   5   Y   1   Kevin
20001003   23.4   5   X   1   Kevin
20001004   23.3   5   Y   1   Steve
20001005   23.4   5   X   1   Steve
```

I would like to read this file and call the data the belongs to Kevin and/or Steve. Something like this:
df['Kevin']
20001001   23.0   5   X   1
20001002   23.1   5   Y   1 
20001003   23.4   5   X   1

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by upload and are you asking how to output to csv for example just the last column? if so then `df['name'].to_csv(file_path)` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define multiple masks and use these to filter your df:

```
In [8]:    
kev_mask = (df['name'] == 'Kevin')
steve_mask = (df['name'] == 'Steve')
df[kev_mask]

Out[8]:
       date  col1  col2 col3  col4   name
0  20001001  23.0     5    X     1  Kevin
1  20001002  23.1     5    Y     1  Kevin
2  20001003  23.4     5    X     1  Kevin

In [9]:    
df[steve_mask]

Out[9]:
       date  col1  col2 col3  col4   name
3  20001004  23.3     5    Y     1  Steve
4  20001005  23.4     5    X     1  Steve

In [10]:    
df[kev_mask | steve_mask]

Out[10]:
       date  col1  col2 col3  col4   name
0  20001001  23.0     5    X     1  Kevin
1  20001002  23.1     5    Y     1  Kevin
2  20001003  23.4     5    X     1  Kevin
3  20001004  23.3     5    Y     1  Steve
4  20001005  23.4     5    X     1  Steve
```